# Select box value getting in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting select box value like code below:

```
$(document).on('change','.test',function(){
   var val = $('option:selected',this).val()
   alert(val);
});
```

How can I get that selected value in below function:

```
function test_data()
{
   //get select box value here
}
```

Comment: invoke `test_data` with value - `test_data(val)`

Comment: This is very simple, you can do some research and can be done easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do like below :

```
var value = $('select.test').val();
alert(value)
```

or you can use on change event

```
<select onchange="test(this.value)" ></select>
<script>
function test(value) {
//value is selected option value
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq6fmn39/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the metod `test_data` on change event of select.

```
$(document).on('change','.test',function(){
    var val = $('option:selected',this).val();
    test_data(val);
    //  alert(val);
});

function test_data(val)
{
    alert(val)
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nekz47us/2/)

**OR**

```
$(document).on('change','.test',test_data);

function test_data()
{
    var val = $('.test option:selected').val();
    alert(val)
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nekz47us/4/)

Answer (score 0):

It's depend -

**1. You can easily pass the value to function.**

```
$(document).on('change','.test',function(){
  var val = $('option:selected',this).val()
  test_data(val);
});

function test_data(val) {
   //get select box value here
}
```

**2. you can store value inside globe variable.**

```
var gval;
$(document).on('change','.test',function(){
  var val = $('option:selected',this).val()
  gval = val;
});

function test_data() {
  alert(gval)
  //get select box value here
}
```

**3. To get value using select element.**

```
function test_data() {
    var value = $('select.test').val();
    alert(value)
}
```